# Setting write permissions for folders while creating a package with MSDeploy

Tags: nant, msdeploy

I'm using MSDeploy to create an artefact as a build step in NAnt. This particular build step is called on successful compilation. The artefact is then used to for deployment.

Here is the step specified in my build file.

```
  <target name="BuildMsDeployPackage" depends="StageForMsDeployPackaging">
    <exec program="${msdeploy.exe}"
          workingdir="${buildDirectory}"
          verbose="true"
          commandline="-verb:sync 
                      -source:iisapp=${packagingDirectory} 
                      -dest:package=${publishDirectory}\${webapp.artifact.zip}"/>
```

The `source` here is my my web project.

I want to be able to set specify write access to a couple of folders in the package that is created. Is this possible? I know that there is a `setAcl` provider for this specific purpose, but can this be used while creating a package?

**Edit**

I am now able to get acl permissions into the `archive.xml` file that is generated along with the package. I'm using the `auto` provider to sync contents of my package with the destination. Does `auto` copy acl's while syncing?

Answer (score 0):

You can set file and directory properties via NAnt's [`<attrib>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/attrib.html) task. In this case you would set `readonly` to `false`.

Comment: Using the `package` provider creates a file called `archive.xml` in the package. I want to be able to set permissions through MSDeploy's `setAcl` command so that they appear in the `archive.xml` file. I am not sure where to give the `setAcl` provider.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any experience with MSDeploy